# Manjero de for en un array en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, loops

Hola tengo un WS que contiene arreglos dinámicos y necesito guardar todas las variables que tengan el estado 'reservado' para después poder utilizarlas.

El web service devuelve estos datos:

> [{"id":"3","rut_medico":"12883277-3","fecha_programada":"2017-02-14","hora_programada":"13:00:00","estado":"reservado"},{"id":"4","rut_medico":"12883277-3","fecha_programada":"2017-02-21","hora_programada":"17:00:00","estado":"reservado"},{"id":"10","rut_medico":"12883277-3","fecha_programada":"2017-02-21","hora_programada":"14:00:00","estado":"reservado"},{"id":"11","rut_medico":"12883277-3","fecha_programada":"2017-02-21","hora_programada":"14:00:00","estado":"reservado"},{"id":"12","rut_medico":"12883277-3","fecha_programada":"2017-02-21","hora_programada":"14:00:00","estado":"null"}]

Aquí esta el codigo:

```
$scope.reservados = {}

Movil.HourofDoctor({
  rut_medico: rut_medico
},function(response) {
  $scope.horamedica = response;

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    response[i]
    if(response[i].estado === 'reservado') {

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: no pongas imagenes, coloca el codigo porfavor

Comment: pero esa imagen no sirve para el código, es para saber como viene estructurado...

Comment: sirve para tratarlo, revisarlo, testearlo con el codigo que hagamos para responder

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no haces: `if (response[i].estado === 'reservado') { $scope.reservedHours.push(response[i]); }`?

Comment: probare... gracias bro

Comment: @Guz escribe la respuesta abajo completa para que te den como respuesta aceptada asi ayudas al sitio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $scope.reservados = {}

Movil.HourofDoctor({
  rut_medico: rut_medico
},function(response) {
  $scope.horamedica = response;
  $scope.reservados = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    response[i]
    if(response[i].estado === 'reservado') {
        $scope.reservados.push(respone[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Simplemente añadiendo un array donde almacenar las reservas que tengan el estado reservado y haciendo push en él cuando el array en la posición del contador coincida.

EDIT: Acabo de ver que lo respondió @Guz en los comentarios.

Comment: gracias  bro me sirvió

Comment: De nada, los meritos a Guz que te respondió en los comentarios de tu pregunta jeje.

Comment: si es verdad  pero  no podia marcar la respuesta como valida. jaja